# Php/Laravel Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel

I'm facing with this error:

> Trying to get property 'first_name' of non-object"

this error is appearing only in live server not in localHost
Here i create the $post:

```
       @foreach($posts as $key => $post)

<td>{{ $post->user->first_name. ' '. $post->user->last_name }}</td>
```

When I output: {{print_r($post->user->first_name)}}, this show me a list of users first name.

Comment: Either `$post` or `$user` or both are not an object. Show us how you created `$post`

Comment: @foreach($posts as $key => $post)

Comment: Thats how you use `$post`, so show us a `print_r($post);`

Comment: {{print_r($post->user->first_name)}} this show me a list of users first name

Comment: PLEASE use the [edit] link and add the output into your question

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You mostly have a post without a user on your production server, maybe a post created for testing?

You can either check your database to fix the issue and make sure that you can't create a post without setting a user to it in your code,

or

You can check if the user is present before echo'ng it

```php
{{ $post->user->first_name??'No author'. ' '. $post->user->last_name??'' }}
```

Comment: Thank for the response, All posts have author, becuase in localHost page works correctly but only on live server I have this error. I use the same database in localhost and in Server.

Comment: @Rinor  Anyway, did you test the code ? also you dont use the "same" database, you use the same structure. the entries are different. i'm not saying a post doesnt have a `user_id` field on the server, i'm saying it is set to `null` on one of the entries.